# How we can use dynamo db local to save cognito ID of authenticate users

Tags: amazon-cognito, dynamo-local

Is there any specific way to create a Cognito Identity Pool in a Amazon DynamoDB local setup? I have already setup the javascript shell and created several tables and have queried it. I need to provide a authenticated mode user login (Facebook, Amazon, Google) for my node application. I found several tutorials about how to set it up using AWS DynamoDB, but I need to know how I can create it using a local DynamoDB without accessing AWS DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB local doesn't validate credentials, so it doesn't matter how you set up the Amazon Cognito identity pool or the roles for the pool. You will be able to interact with the CognitoCredentials object the same way if you are using Amazon DynamoDB or DynamoDB local.

It is important to note that you will not hoever be able to validate fine-grained access control unless you use the full service, again because DynamoDB local doesn't validate credentials.

Comment: @ManishaRatnapala Again, there will be no difference in how you use the Amazon Cognito identity id whether you use Amazon DynamoDB or DynamoDB local. You should create the identity pool as if you are going to use it with Amazon DynamoDB, because I assume eventually you will use the real service.